# Convert TagName into <TagName></TagName> with a shortcut in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've encountered this behaviour several times when using ctrl+c and ctrl+v in VS Code, but never could figure out what exactly I've pressed.
I misspressed the buttons and got this.

There's a combination that converts a selection like TagName (should be selected)
into .

I've looked through the list of shortcuts and wasn't able to find one.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can press `tab` to use it. So for example, you have `ul`, press `tab` and get `<ul></ul>`.

For more informations, look [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very annoying - knowing that the feature exists and not being able to use it. Also, I've noticed that it behaves differently in .html and .js files.